# Noetherian affine schemes for which localization computes the values of the structure sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

Is there a non-tautological characterization of the class of commutative unital Noetherian rings satisfying the following property: for any open subset $U$ of the topological space of $\mathrm{Spec}\,R$, the natural map from the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative set of global functions not vanishing anywhere on $U$ to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}\,R}(U)$ is an isomorphism? Some interesting sufficient conditions at least?

Note that [not all](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3217070/251240) commutative unital Noetherian rings satisfy this property.